# Is it possible to download 45° (bird's eye ) image from google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I want to get some bird's eye images from google map for research purpose only. Given the center latitude/longitude and zoom level, I hope the API can return the corresponding image tile, just like [Google Static Map API](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) does. Following is an example of Google Static Map API and the returned map tile.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=satellite&center=37.530101,38.600062&zoom=14&size=640x400
```

image tile returned by above URL
[image: url screenshot]

My question is: Given the center latitude/longitude and zoom level, is there any Google Map API or approach that can return the Bird's eye image tile like the above Static Map API example?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Google Static Maps API doesn't have this feature implemented.

However, there is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3796

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote, hopefully one day Google will implement it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Google has JavaScript API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes) which can generate 45° image, but cannot return you the image tile.